# Problem at installing cpx210x driver ob Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, system-installation, 22.04, arduino

I've got a problem at installing the cp210x driver for Arduino on my ubuntu system.
The os version is 22.04 (64bit):

I follow this tutorial:
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/release-notes/Linux_CP210x_VCP_2.6.x_Release_Notes.txt

The command "make clean" works fine, but if i run the command "make cp210x", i get this error message:

```
ssv@jsz:~/Documents/Linux_2.6.x_VCP_Driver_Source$ make cp210x
cc     cp210x.c   -o cp210x
cp210x.c:18:10: fatal error: linux/slab.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <linux/slab.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: cp210x] Error 1
```

Can someone help me?

Thx

Comment: Install the `build-essential` package (`sudo apt install build-essential`), it's a meta-package that includes the compiler,  linker and include files. Or, you could find the package providing the file with `dpkg -S /usr/include/linux/slab.h`, and install that package.

Comment: THX i solved the Problem :)

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.